# WP7 How to add the style in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created a style for button control in App.xaml("RoundButton"). I want to create a button in C# code and set the style of the button to the one created in App.xaml file. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: can i ask why you want to create a button in c#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Style= (Style)App.Current.Resources["RoundButton"];
```